# JAVA google geocoding API get city

Tags: java, google-maps, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to get the Country and City names from latitude and longtitude using google geocoding API. 
This library https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java
as a JAVA implementation for the API.

This is the current way i'm making it:

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey("AI... my key");
GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.newRequest(context)
        .latlng(new LatLng(40.714224, -73.961452)).language("en").resultType(AddressType.COUNTRY, AddressType.ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1).await();

logger.info("Results lengh: "+ results.length);

for(int i =0; i< results[0].addressComponents.length; i++) {
    logger.info("Address components "+i+": "+results[0].addressComponents[i].shortName);
}
```

**The problem is:**
There is a 5 levels of `AddressType.ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1` and city name is on different levels depends on specific location/country. 
So the question is - how can i extract exactly the city name from the results? or how do i need form a request properly ?

P.S. it is not a mobile app.

Comment: `administrative_area_level_2` should be city

Comment: as i mention before, for the different countries/locations city shown up on different "administrative_area_level_2" (1-5).

Comment: provide examples, give me the complete url except api key, i have my own api key, i will also hit. :)

Comment: emm. sry, example for what?
if you mean different geographic coordinates - example this Sydney (lat, lng: -33.8984101,151.2141271) vs. this, Bangkok (13.7542408,100.5142316)

Comment: yes i understand that , i have used this api for long now, what i have observed is we cannot rely 100% on google data

Comment: Just a sidenote: I have worked in the field of geolocation information services with [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com) and I wanted to share a warning. Google Mapping Services's Terms of Service say that you cannot use their results without displaying them on a map. There are other legal restrictions too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AddressComponentType.LOCALITY` to get [city name](http://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.1.3/javadoc/com/google/maps/model/AddressComponentType.html#LOCALITY) from `GeocodingResult`

I do it on this way:

```
private PlaceName parseResult(GeocodingResult r) {

    PlaceName placeName = new PlaceName(); // simple POJO

    for (AddressComponent ac : r.addressComponents) {
        for (AddressComponentType acType : ac.types) {

            if (acType == AddressComponentType.ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1) {

                placeName.setStateName(ac.longName);

            } else if (acType == AddressComponentType.LOCALITY) {

                placeName.setCityName(ac.longName);

            } else if (acType == AddressComponentType.COUNTRY) {

                placeName.setCountry(ac.longName);
            }
        }

        if(/* your condition */){ // got required data
            break;
        }
    }

    return placeName;
}
```